# Rapid web-form development in liferay portal

Tags: forms, liferay, portlet, orbeon, xforms

I am looking for rapid web-form development technologies which can be deployed inside the liferay portal.

I know orbeon xform are deployable as portlet inside a liferay portal. Are there any other competing java products/technologies.

Here is the [link](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-separate-deployment-with-portlets) to user orbeon xform as portlet.

Comment: I am not sure describing Orbeon Forms as a RAD is the best way to put it: Orbeon Forms, and in particular Form Builder, is specifically designed to create and manage forms, not any type of web application.

Comment: thanks for the response . Do you know of any  RAD tool for form development which can be used for portal deployment ?

Comment: I've never needed one or researched the topic, and I don't have any particular recommendation. If you're looking into doing data capture with forms, then Orbeon Forms and Form Builder might be the right tool for you, but if you're looking for a RAD, I think you'll have to look for other solutions.